# How to receive event when user changes system's culture

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo

When my application run with a specified culture. Don't close the application, user changes system's culture, ex: change number decimal separator from "." to ",". How to my application can catch this event. Thanks.

**Notes:** C# 2.0, Windows Form.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can handle the `SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged` event:

```
void SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged(object sender, UserPreferenceChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Regional settings have changed
    if (e.Category == UserPreferenceCategory.Locale)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how to get new regional settings?

Comment: I solve my problem with the code: CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();

Comment: @Lu Lu, I didn't know about that method... learn something every day ;)

Comment: When user change system's culture. The CultureInfo.CurrentCulture is old settings, you must call CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData() to clear old settings and get new settings.

Comment: I ran into a problem with ClearCachedDate and found this SO that solves the problem. I had to spin up a task and return the results of the cache clear. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370533/cultureinfo-clearcacheddata-does-not-work-it-randomly-sometimes-works-sometimes

Answer (score 3):

If you want to trach system language changes then you have SystemEvents object which contains [UserPreferenceChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.userpreferencechanged.aspx) event you can attach to.

Sample:

```
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged += new UserPreferenceChangedEventHandler(SystemEvents_UserPreferenceChanged);
```

If you want to track input language changes (like changes in system try when you choose between languages), then you can use: System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage.[CurrentInputLanguage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage.currentinputlanguage.aspx)

Sample:

```
string inputLanguage = System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.LayoutName;
```