# Get regional settings dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms

In my winforms application, I have to display a list of events (like buttons' clicks) with the time of each of them. The time format has to be the same as Windows regional settings. So I'm using `DateTimeoffset.ToLocalTime().ToString()` for that which is working perfectly.

If I change Windows regional settings (time zone or format) while the application is running, the time is still displayed on the old format. As a workaround, I have to restart the application so it will grab the new regional settings.

Is there a way to get these settings on the fly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to receive event when user changes system's culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711555/how-to-receive-event-when-user-changes-systems-culture)

Answer (score -1):

try calling this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData()
```

and then retrying your local time call

Comment: When would he need to call it?

Comment: That works. But clearing the cache for each event seems not a good idea

Comment: @Mhd take a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711555/how-to-receive-event-when-user-changes-systems-culture

If that event fires for changing the time, then clear the cache