# Detected system language change C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want function that acts on language of system change.
For example,when the language changed from English to Spanish,etc.

Here is my code, I have used this code in loop to check again and again either language changed or not but it not working.
When I change my system language sometime it hault and sometime it give same name again and again.

```
string current_language=InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.Culture.Name;
string current_layout = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.LayoutName;
```

Is there any solution?

[image: Here I have add image of language bar where I change my language]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4711600/2716623

Comment: What you are referring to is the input language, not the system language. It's per-thread, not per-system. You also need to tell what you are using for your application (winforms, wpf, uwp).

Comment: I am asking about current language of system. I am using window form

Comment: I have tried to receive event when user changes system's culture but its not working..@vasily.sib

Comment: Because it's not the system culture, it's the current input language. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.inputlanguagechanged?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: answer updated below

Answer (score 0):

`CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture` for system install language
`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` for user regional settings (numeric formatting preference)
`CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` for current user language

The current thread gets its culture info on startup from its launching thread and it can be "changed from within" like this `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");` but to detect "change from without" you need to ask Windows.  Here is a simple demo calling `GetUserDefaultLCID()` using P/Invoke.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Threading;

    namespace ConsoleApp2
    {
      class Program
      {
        private static readonly Dictionary<uint, CultureInfo> Cultures;

        static Program()
        {
          Cultures = new Dictionary<uint, CultureInfo>
                     { // These just happen to be what I have installed
                       { 0x0809, new CultureInfo("en-GB") },
                       { 0x0409, new CultureInfo("en-US") }, 
                       { 0x1C09, new CultureInfo("en-ZA") }
                     };
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")] static extern uint GetUserDefaultLCID();

        static void MonitorCulture()
        {
          while (true)
          {
            Console.WriteLine($"CurrentUICulture    : {Cultures[GetUserDefaultLCID()].EnglishName}");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
          }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          var monitor = new Thread(MonitorCulture);
          monitor.Start();
          Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit...");
          Console.ReadKey();
        }
      }
    }
```

Which produced this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sou6y.png as I changed Language while the program was running.

Comment: I have used this but its not working...I have add two language but when I switch language it doesn't show different name.

Comment: @MobeenGhaffar Answer updated with further explanation and example